# svg issue with safari when zooming in

Tags: html, css, svg, safari

I have an svg that is using some values with pixels (cx, cy, r). When I open it in Safari and I do cmd + "+" or cmd + "-" everything messes up. I don't know how to fix this. This problem doesn't happen with Chrome.

The computed values for those styles change when doing one of those 2 actions. I don't want them to change.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.container {
  width: 28%;
  height: 28%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.circle {
  transform-origin: center center;
}
.circle-1 {
  transform: rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(0);
  stroke-dasharray: 220;
  stroke-dashoffset: 20;
}
.circle-2 {
  transform: rotateZ(540deg) translateZ(0);
  stroke-dasharray: 176;
  stroke-dashoffset: 20;
}
.circle-3 {
  transform: rotateZ(72deg) translateZ(0);
  stroke-dasharray: 132;
  stroke-dashoffset: 30;
}
```

```html
<!-- To reproduce, open in Safari e.g. Safari 10.1 and click command + "+". The positioning for the circles changes. This doesn't happen in Chrome -->

<svg class="container" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 73 73">
  <circle class="circle circle-1" cx="36.5" cy="36.5" r="35" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2"></circle>
  <circle class="circle circle-2" cx="36.5" cy="36.5" r="28" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2"></circle>
  <circle class="circle circle-3" cx="36.5" cy="36.5" r="21" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2"></circle>
</svg>
```

Here is a codepen:
https://codepen.io/Ostos/pen/WZbGRW

Comment: Have you find out what's the solution?

Comment: No, I had to use a png, but I'm still curious on how to fix this because I don't like the idea of having to switch to use a png for this